# Is there a way to query the AUTHID property setting for a list of Oracle Stored Packages?

Tags: oracle, authid

Does any one know of an easy way (short of parsing the top of each package definition) to see the AUTHID property settings for a list of Oracle packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query `[DBA|ALL|USER]_PROCEDURES`.  Specifically, the `AUTHID` column

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create or replace package authid_pkg
  2    authid current_user
  3  as
  4    procedure foo;
  5    procedure bar;
  6* end;
  7  /

Package created.

SQL> select owner, object_name, procedure_name, authid
  2    from all_procedures
  3   where object_name = 'AUTHID_PKG';

OWNER                          OBJECT_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
PROCEDURE_NAME                 AUTHID
------------------------------ ------------
SCOTT                          AUTHID_PKG
FOO                            CURRENT_USER

SCOTT                          AUTHID_PKG
BAR                            CURRENT_USER

SCOTT                          AUTHID_PKG
                               CURRENT_USER
```